# Javascript Code Simplification Cheat Sheet

Tags: javascript

Does anyone have any idea where I can get a Cheat Sheet or a Guide on how to simplify Javascript code e.g. a list of common simplifications?!

For example, the following code:

`(var_name === 'joe') ? true : false`

can be simplified to:

`!!((var_name === 'joe'))`

Or will `UglifyJS` (and/or other code compressors) do this already?!

Thanks.

Comment: `var_name==='joe'` is enough, but you shouldn't need to worry about minification if you're using a minifier.

Comment: Shorter and Simpler are different things.

Comment: @zzzzBov Ok. I already use UglifyJS but I wasn't sure if it does simplification as I only use it to minify

Comment: @Quentin Sure...that's why the title says 'Simplification'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of this is just common sense. After all, "if x is true, then true; else false" is pretty obviously the same as "x". A lot more is just the product of experience. It's not clear if you are looking for refactoring that improves execution performance or whether you are after maintainability and readability. Many JavaScript idioms address both issues, but some idioms balance one against the other.

Having said that, there are several guides to JavaScript idioms (which you can find with a simple web search). The most useful one (in my opinion) is Crockford's [*The Elements of JavaScript Style*](http://javascript.crockford.com/style2.html). Another good source is [*Principles of Writing Consistent, Idiomatic JavaScript*](https://github.com/rwldrn/idiomatic.js/).

Comment: Thanks a lot. The `Principles of Writing Consistent, Idiomatic Javascript` was in line with what I was looking for. Cheers.